# Aналог функции func (*Buffer) Next в POC::FIFOBuffer

Tags: c++, golang, poco

В языке Go есть функция func (*Buffer) Next, которая берет из Buffer срез(массив) из n элементов.

```
276  // Next returns a slice containing the next n bytes from the buffer,
   277  // advancing the buffer as if the bytes had been returned by Read.
   278  // If there are fewer than n bytes in the buffer, Next returns the entire buffer.
   279  // The slice is only valid until the next call to a read or write method.
   280  func (b *Buffer) Next(n int) []byte {
   281      b.lastRead = opInvalid
   282      m := b.Len()
   283      if n > m {
   284          n = m
   285      }
   286      data := b.buf[b.off : b.off+n]
   287      b.off += n
   288      if n > 0 {
   289          b.lastRead = opRead
   290      }
   291      return data
   292  }
```

Как реализовать подобную вещь, используя [Poco/FIFOBuffer.h](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.BasicFIFOBuffer.html#12212)

```
#include "Poco/FIFOBuffer.h"
#include "Poco/Buffer.h"

using Poco::FIFOBuffer;
using Poco::Buffer;

void main()
{   
    char* qr = "";
    std::string str = "test";
    FIFOBuffer buf(12);
    buf.write(str.c_str(), 4);
    std::cout << buf[0]; // t
    buf.read(qr, 1); // прекращена работа программы
    // std::memcpy(pBuffer, _buffer.begin() + _begin, length * sizeof(T)); Вот здесь вылетает.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вызове `buf.read(qr, 1)` также происходит вызов `memcpy`:

```
std::memcpy(pBuffer, _buffer.begin() + _begin, length * sizeof(T));
```

Здесь вы пытаетесь произвести [запись в константу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24349418/4651282), что приводит к ошибке.
Если говорить в терминах C++, то как сказано в примечании к пункту 16 раздела 2.13.5 стандарта C++ эффект при попытке изменить строковый литерал не определен:

> The eﬀect of attempting to modify a string literal is undeﬁned.

Рабочий пример:

```
#include "Poco/FIFOBuffer.h"
#include "Poco/Buffer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{   
    std::string str = "Hello world";
    char arr[8]={},arr2;
    Poco::FIFOBuffer buf(12);
    buf.write(str.data(),str.size());
    buf.read(arr,7);
    std::cout<<arr<<"\n";
    buf.read(&arr2,1);
    std::cout<<arr2<<"\n";
}
```